# React + Jest: How to test private styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Charities` component that shows text "Sorry..." when the `status` prop is `=== "error"`:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Notification = styled.p`
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  display: ${props => (props.hide ? "none" : "block")};
`;

const ErrorNotification = styled(Notification)`
  background: #e3c7c4;
`;

export const Charities = ({
  ..., status
}) => (
  <Container>
    <ErrorNotification hide={status !== "error"}>
      Sorry, something was wrong with your payment. Please try again.
    </ErrorNotification>
    ...
  </Container>
);

export default Charities;
```

I'm trying to test this with jest like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Charities } from "./index";

describe("Charities", () => {
  let props;
  let mountedCharities;
  const charities = () => {
    if (!mountedCharities) {
      mountedCharities = mount(<Charities {...props} />);
    }
    return mountedCharities;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      status: undefined,
      ...
    };
    mountedCharities = undefined;
  });

  describe("when status is pending", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      props.status = "pending";
    });

    it("doesn't render error", () => {
      expect(charities().text()).not.toMatch(/Sorry/); // <---------- FAILS
    });
  });
});
```

My test fails with:

```
Expected value not to match:
  /Sorry/
Received:
  "Sorry, something was wrong with your payment. Please try again.Congratulations! You have successfully made a donation."
```

It seems like it's loading the children of the styled components even when it doesn't meet the conditions. How would I test this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the attribute hide which maps to 'display: none' when true this still renders the component albeit invisibly you should do something like this instead:

```
{ status === "error" && 
  <ErrorNotification >
     Sorry, something was wrong with your payment. Please try again.
  </ErrorNotification>
}
```

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I think we should share the spoils, assuming Edmund ever comes back to this, besides I do need the rep more than you! I can't even comment on your post yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected, it's just that `styled()` works by putting class names on the elements to control the styling.

In the unit test `ErrorNotification` is still there but it has css classes on it that will give it `display: none` in the final rendered HTML.

To make your components easier to unit test I recommend doing the hiding within `Charities` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Notification = styled.p`
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  display: block;
`;

const ErrorNotification = styled(Notification)`
  background: #e3c7c4;
`;

export const Charities = ({
  ..., status
}) => (
  <Container>
    {status !== "error" ? null : (
      <ErrorNotification>
        Sorry, something was wrong with your payment. Please try again.
      </ErrorNotification>
    )}
    ...
  </Container>
);

export default Charities;
```

That way if the status in the props for `Charities` is anything except `'error'` then `ErrorNotification` won't be rendered at all.

Comment: haha, looks like Code Ranger answered with the same approach as I was finishing.  Hopefully my answer gives context around what is happening and why this approach is recommended